# VSCode. Как командой изменить одинаковые слова на другое слово. Может это расширение?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, visual-studio-code, vim

Я пользуюсь Vim в vscode. Хочу делать также, часто попадается случай когда нужно изменить также слова. Как это сделать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как именно ты используешь vim в vscode? На картинке пример именно `ctrl+d` - в файле, который позволяет выделить несколько одинаковых участков

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это горячие клавиши Cntr+d:)))

Comment: ноуп, не работает.Скорее всего изза вим. Есть варианты с расширениями? У меня вообще проблема с выделением одинаковых слов, я меняю с помощью команды %s/nameOfTarget/nameOfYouWant/gc и потом еще y Нужно щелкать y да, изменить или n если нет, перейти на следующее похожее слово)

Comment: Сперва курсор подводите к тому слову которое нужно выделить, потом еще раз нажимаете, курсор находит дубль и выделяет его, если еще нужно, то еще раз ctrl+d, у меня так работает

Comment: почему то я такой человек, который ищет причину сказать почему у меня не работает, чем взять совет и эмплиментировать его. Ctrl + d прекрасно работает, спасибо, просто удалил Вимовскую команду! Правда если слово к примеру target и Target или target и targetName оно считает их как разных, но на случай если я все же захочу, или к примеру я хочу выделить 1, 2 не хочу, 3 хочу, как это сделать?) Спасибо еще раз всем!

Comment: Если только зажать альт и мышкой тыкнуть в нужное место таким образом продублировать курсор, и только потом изменять слово. Если есть разница в регистре или букве, то это разные слова:)

Answer (score 1):

если хотите изменить код или слова можно восползоватся горячими клавишами ctrl + r вылезет окошка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю ребят, но я убедился что у меня расскладка vim перебивает родную ии воспользовался методом cntr + d. Ваш метод у меня к сожалению не сработал. Спасибо за помощь!